# how do I export unreal engine material?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I tried exported u4e material and use them in other programs but I can't.

how do I export unreal engine's material for use in other 3d programm like 3ds max or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnrealEngine4 materials (shaders) are only compatible to UE4 tools itself and cannot be exported to be edited by other tools.

However, you can bake materials as textures, if that is enough for you:

- [Render To Texture Blueprint Toolset](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Content/Tools/RenderToTextureTools)
- [Baking Materials to Textures | Live Training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaM_owaUpbE) (by Epic)